# How can I assign RGB color codes to a WORD?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, mfc, windows-ce

I am assigning the color values to the display frame buffer, and that buffer pointer return type is BYTE. But i am not able to assign the RGB color value into it. This i am doing to set the pixel location using directdraw on WINCE platform .Here is the snapshot code.

```
BYTE* pDisplayMemOffset = (BYTE*) ddsd.lpSurface;

int x = 100;

int y = 100;

pDisplayMemOffset += x*ddds.lXPitch + y*ddds.lPitch ;

***(WORD*)pDisplayMemOffset = 0x0f00;
```

But how i can assign RGB(100,150,100) combination in this, i have tried to put DWORD instead of WORD while assigment but it desnt work. i knw i required hex value for color in 0x000000 format(RGB), but i think BYTE cnt store such large value into it.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://www3.telus.net/alexander_russell/course_dx/chapter_2_dx.htm) is what you're looking for? Check the sample code under the "Single Pixel" section.

Answer (score 1):

How this assignment can be done is very dependent on the pixel-format you specified when acquiring `ddsd`. See the field `ddpfPixelFormat` and also specifically in there: `dwRGBBitCount`.

Maybe you can provide this pixel format information so that i can improve my answer. However, i can easily give you an example of how you do this pixel-color assignment if e.g. the pixel-format is:

```
[1 byte red] [1 byte green] [1 byte blue] [1 byte unused]
```

Here's the example:

```
*(pDisplayMemOffset+0) = 0x10;// asigning 0x10 to the red-value of first pixel
*(pDisplayMemOffset+1) = 123; // asigning 123 to green-value of first pixel 
                              // (no need for hex)
*(pDisplayMemOffset+4) = 200; // asigning 200 to red-value of second pixel
                              // (BYTE is unsigned)
```

If you have to extract the color values from an integer it largely depends on which byte-ordering and color-ordering that integer was given in, but you can try it out easily.

First i would try this:

```
*(((unsigned int*)pDisplayMemOffset)+0) = 0x1A2A3A4A
*(((unsigned int*)pDisplayMemOffset)+1) = 0x1B2B3B4B
```

If this works, then the pixel-format had either an unused 4th byte (like my example above) or an alpha-value that is now set to one of the values. Again: aside from the pixel-format also the ordering of the bytes in your integer decides whether this directly works or whether you have to do some byte-swapping.